# Sweave xtable: how to position tables between text?

Tags: r, latex, sweave, xtable

I have a number of tables with text around them describing them.  Something like this:

```
This table shows blah blah...

<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
print(
    xtable(x,
        caption = "blah", label = "tab:four", table.placement = "tbp", caption.placement = "top")
  , size = "small", table.placement="ht")
@

This table shows blah blah...

<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
print(
    xtable(x,
        caption = "blah", label = "tab:five", table.placement = "tbp", caption.placement = "top")
  , size = "small", table.placement="ht")
@
```

I want all my descriptive text to be in line with the tables so that they follow in the sequence that I am writing them.  But around the end of a page, some tables move off onto the next page and the descriptive text is just free floating.  Is there some particular `table.placement` command that will ensure that everything stays the way that it is written?

Comment: Using the latex package longtable does also help sometimes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See here for the [table](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_table_environment_-_captioning_etc) placement. You could try "!h" to force the table to stay where you wan't.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up setting the table.placement above to "!h" and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 12):

The latex `float` package provides the float specifier `H`, which allows you to force tables and figures to be precisely in the location they occur in the latex code. For example:

```
\usepackage{float} 

...

<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
print(xtable(x),table.placement="H")
@
```

Comment: Thanks!  That's very helpful!  Although !h seemed to work better.

Answer (score 3):

I find `\clearpage` after a float is sometimes useful.